# mod_rewrite .htaccess directory using wildcards?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I use wildcards to reference the same directory in my rule? I need blog_name to be the wild card, so the script checks if there is a file in the old_site directory and if it is, rewrites to it. Currently it works for one directory:

```
RewriteRule ^blog_name/([^/\.]+) old_site/blog_name/$1.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So I need blog_name to be ANY directory:

```
RewriteRule ^[*wildcard_dir*]/([^/\.]+) old_site/[*wildcard_dir*]/$1.php [NC,QSA]
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/\.]+) old_site/$1/$2.php [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect, if you wouldn't mind can you tell me why the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f got flipped up above the rewrite rule?

Comment: `RewriteCond` it's condition for first rule above.